# GSP rendering issue after server is idle overnight

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, gsp

I have been intermittently encountering a difficult to replicate issue now for a few weeks.  It seems (ie I can't yet be sure) that if the Grails app is not touched overnight something is perhaps unloaded causing:

GSP rendered with values such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@72cd722b" content="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@4e520b18">

<link href="/appname/static/bundle-bundle_application_head.css" type="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@31da0262" rel="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@774121fe" media="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@6008482c" />

<body style="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@49533701">

<a href="/appname/register/forgotPassword" name="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@815a651" class="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils@5689bde">Forgotten Password?</a>
```

This occurs deployed to Tomcat standalone and also has once leaving Grails running overnight in IntelliJ.

It doesn't happen every night but on most and I can't yet track down what the difference is between working and not working.

Nothing in the logs of the either the application or Tomcat to give a clue.

At this point I'm wondering if it is to do with the resources plugin.  But any thoughts on what to look at are appreciated

Environment:

```
   OS Win7 x64 and Redhat 5
Tomcat 7.0.x (also was occuring on latest Glassfish)
Grails 2.0.4
Plugins: 
plugins.cache=1.0.0.RC1
plugins.cache-headers=1.1.5
plugins.compress=0.4
plugins.console=1.1
plugins.executor=0.3
plugins.export=1.3
plugins.fields=1.1
plugins.google-visualization=0.5.2
plugins.grails-melody=1.13
plugins.joda-time=1.4
plugins.mail=1.0
plugins.p6spy=0.5
plugins.quartz-monitor=0.2
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.7.3
plugins.springcache=1.3.1
plugins.zipped-resources=1.0
```

**Update #1:**

Occured again over this weekend, on using Tomcat manager to reload the webapp it fails with the following message **but this does not occur on a fresh start of Tomcat**:

```
 INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 3, 2012 7:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.joda.time.DurationFieldType.hour() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: hours(), wait(), days(), eras(), years(), any()
    at grails.plugin.jodatime.taglib.PeriodTagLib$_getPeriodTypeForFields_closure3.doCall(PeriodTagLib.groovy:87)
    at grails.plugin.jodatime.taglib.PeriodTagLib.getPeriodTypeForFields(PeriodTagLib.groovy:87)
    at grails.plugin.jodatime.taglib.PeriodTagLib.<clinit>(PeriodTagLib.groovy:84)
    ... 4 more
```

Which I don't believe as the code in the jodaTime plugin looks ok:

```
   Line 84: private static final PeriodType DEFAULT_PERIOD_TYPE = getPeriodTypeForFields("hours,minutes,seconds")

    private static PeriodType getPeriodTypeForFields(String fields) {
    Line 87:    def fieldTypes = fields.split(/\s*,\s*/).collect { DurationFieldType."$it"() } as DurationFieldType[]
```

**Update #2**

Melody shows that slowly all the Physical memory being gobbled up

Could be related to these log entries if the app is reloaded (and always forces a Tomcat shutdown and start with a hanging java process to be killed)

```
SEVERE: The web application [/appname] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 31, 2012 6:04:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/appname] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 31, 2012 6:04:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
```

or it is something along these lines: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#cclThreadSpawnedByCommonClassLoader

**Update #3**

Physical memory issue resolved and the app is still broken, looking like the original posting.  This time after less idle (a couple of hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was having this line in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
String.metaClass.mixin StringUtils
```

I eventually removed this and have been testing ok now for over 24 hours under all conditions that had ordinarily caused the issue.

This I had followed from this posting a long time ago from here: [Groovy GDK equivalent of Apache Commons StringUtils.capitalize(str) or Perl's ucfirst(str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681807/groovy-gdk-equivalent-of-apache-commons-stringutils-capitalizestr-or-perls-uc)

There is some relationship in the error and the code that gave this away but to be honest I am still really at a loss as to what is going on in the mixin to do this over time...back to the books for me.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. Unfortunately I am hitting the issue as well but have little information on the cause; the best I can offer is that it didn't happen at Grails 1.1, does happen in Grails 2.2.0, and has been filed as http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10462.